# VSCode ms-python extension doesn't install in remote SSH with no extension log

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm working on remote Ubuntu 20.04 environment by remote SSH, when a new python file is opened, VSCode recommends me to install the python extension(the one developed by Microsoft) so I click the `install in SSH:<machine name>` button. Then this installation never completes. Checking the `OUPTUT/Log (Remote Server)` window, no extra logs can be found.

I tried installing other extensions and there was always extra printing on the log window like

```
Download extension: <extension name> /tmp/xxxx
Installation completed. <extension name>
```

Any idea how to even debug this issue?